# Flutter - Validate TextFormField only When TextField lost focus

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question about validating the text form field.

Is there a way to only validate the value of a `TextFormField` only when it lost focus?

I want to call an API to check if the username already exists in my database when the focus is changed. If I set `autoValidate` in `TextFormField` true it will validate every time the user press a key. So if a username has 20 characters it will call my API 20 times. Hence to remove overhead I want to call API only when the focus is changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can attach a focusNode to `TextField` so whenever focus changes you can make an api call and validate the text. Inside your class try this

```
FocusNode focusNode;
bool _hasInputError;
String text;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = new FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          _hasInputErro = //Check your conditions on text variable
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And in `TextField` do this

```
TextField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
     errorText: _hasInputError ? "Your error message" : null,
   ),
   onChanged: (String _text) {
     text = _text;
   },
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ayush !! That is working perfectly ! I really Appreciate !!!!!! Thanks :)

Comment: You can accept my answer to help others find the solution easily.

Comment: Sorry for the time... i accept your answer :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

*I have not found any shortcut way. But I have made a code as follow which is working for me.*

```
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FocusNode textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool canCleartextFieldError = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addListener();
  }  
  
  addListener(){
    textFieldFocusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        canCleartextFieldError = textFieldFocusNode.hasFocus;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      key: formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,
              validator: (text) {
                return canCleartextFieldError == true? null: text == ''? 'please enter text here...': null;
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Button'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() { canCleartextFieldError = false; });
                if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  // Todo: do your valid job here...
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Studying this method worked great for me