# Flutter - How to add shadow in TextFormField on focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

How can I add a shadow in a TextFormField when focusing in Flutter? I want the field to have this appearance:

[image: field with shadow]

So far I managed to apply the border when focusing but I don't see any option to apply a shadow:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      hoverColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1))),
);
```

Any ideas on how to get this effect?

Comment: You could try wrapping the `TextFormField` in `Material` and change the `Material`'s elevation

Comment: @Ovidiu the problem with that approach is that I would get the shadow even when the widget is not focused and I don't want that. Only apply the shadow when focusing the input. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can control the shadow of `Material` through its `elevation`. An `elevation` of `0` will result in no shadow. Use a listener on the `FocusNode` of the `TextFormField` to change the `Material`'s elevation when the field is focused - I'm guessing you're already using the same mechanism for changing the border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

important: wrap your `TextField` with `Form` widget and assign `_formKey`
it helps to prevent dismiss the keyboard after `setState()`

complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: focusNode.hasFocus ? BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 6)]) : null,
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              hoverColor: Colors.white,
              filled: true,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/boS20.jpg

Comment: But when error is appear, boxshadow also show on behind errortext. so can you give any solution on it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
 Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow:  [new BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 5.0, // You can set this blurRadius as per your requirement
              ),]
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  hoverColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1))),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the shadow remains even when the input is not focused and I need it only when it gained focus.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376873/11404883